Robots faking being humans
I watched this movie when I was kid, so I don't remember the title, but I can tell a piece of the plot, and I believe it was released before the 2000s.
In this world there are androids, they are developing themselves to better camouflage between the humans. I remember a scene where a woman found a wounded soldier and started talking to him about the evolution of the androids, where the newer models have even flesh and blood. If my memory doesn't fail me there is a model of a child crying they got rid of because they found out he was one of them, but the woman remembered there's a model of a wounded soldier too, so she cut his hand to certify he was not a robot, and he complained about the pain, so she thought he was not a robot, but in the course of the film they found out he was a robot as well.
This scene reminded me of the plot of Terminator Salvation, where Marcus is a hybrid between human and machine and he didn't know he was a machine.
Can anyone recognize the title?

It's been a while, but you might be talking about Screamers from 1995 with Peter Weller.

On a distant mining planet ravaged by a decade of war, scientists have created the perfect weapon: a blade-wielding, self-replicating race of killing devices known as Screamers designed for one purpose only -- to hunt down and destroy all enemy life. But man's greatest weapon has continued to evolve without any human guidance, and now it has devised a new mission: to obliterate all life.

IIRC, there are screamers disguised as kids in distress and wounded soldiers. Here's the trailer:




I'm going to check this out, I'll be back to confirm soon.

Well, you didn't hear this from me, but the full movie is currently available on Youtube.

Based on the Philip K Dick story, Second Variety. Well worth a read. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Variety
